# Set background colors of cells based on the value inside cell

Tags: jquery, html, css, dynamic-tables

I have a table that is populated with random numbers and I need to have a color set to the background of each cell based on the number in that cell to an rgba color. Now these number change on refresh so colors should change if number values change. How can I go about this? Thanks!

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>636407029</td>
        <td>612541294</td>
        <td>870806031</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>110235053</td>
        <td>924102758</td>
        <td>221478283</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>572041102</td>
        <td>236316470</td>
        <td>781401130</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: How you convert `636407029` to RGBA ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
$(".table-bordered td").each(function(){
$(this).attr("bgcolor",$(this).html());
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JCVnY/15/)

**html**

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="636407029">636407029</td>
    <td>612541294</td>
    <td>870806031</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>110235053</td>
    <td>924102758</td>
    <td>221478283</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>572041102</td>
    <td>236316470</td>
    <td>781401130</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: @AnnoopJoshi I tried something similar to this, but didn't work and I thought it was me. I see it works in your fiddle but it won't work with my code :/

Comment: there is no table tag in your html. Try after giving it

Comment: let me update my HTML above, cause I do have the table tag, sorry about that.

Comment: @urbanrunic I suspect, it may over ride with some other style

Comment: thanks! I figured it out. It was over-ridden and I had to fix the styles. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do something like:

```
$("td").each(function () {
    var new_color = make_color_from_content($(this).text());
    $(this).css("background-color", new_color);
});
```

Of course you will have to write some function (make_color_from_content) to convert the value from "636407029" -for example- to "rgba(xxx,xxx,xxx,x)".

Answer (score 0):

This should work - if you write transformNumberToColour function that is.

```
$("td").each(function(){
    $element = $(this);
    val = Number($element.html());
    rgbColour = transformNumberToColour(val); // not shure how you want to do this
    $element.css('background-color', rgbColour);
});
```